Python: What functions are there to inspect the arguments of a decorator?
I have a series of functions which use decorators to mark the "category" of function they are in a pipeline (ingress, process, egress, etc.). For example:
@custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Ingress)
def my_task(<arg1>, <arg2>, ...):
    ...

Below is a simplified version of the custom_task decorator:
def custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Unknown):
    def wrapper(func):
        def executor(*args, **kwargs):
            func.__task_type__ = task_type
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return executor
    return wrapper

I understand that the code has to be ran initially in order for the __task_type__ attribute to be created/populated. However, is there a way (using inspect, or some other obscure library) to view the kwargs default for the task_type parameter in the custom_task decorator of the my_task function; before running my_task? Thanks.
EDIT:
To be more specific, I still have traditional decorator behavior in addition to assigning the function an attribute with some enum. For example:
def custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Unknown):
    def wrapper(func):
        def executor(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                # Behavior for logging exceptions within database
                ...
        func.__task_type__ = task_type
        return executor
    return wrapper

Perhaps it would make more sense to simply have two decorators and decouple the error logging/attribute assigning behavior?
EDIT 2:
It looks like decoupling the error logging/attribute assigning behavior allows for both desired behaviors. See below for final product.
@custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Ingress)
@log_exceptions
def my_task(<arg1>, <arg2>, ...):
   ...

_NO_ARG = object()

def custom_task(arg=_NO_ARG):
    if callable(arg):
        func = arg
        func.__task_type__ = TaskType.Unknown
        return func
    if arg is _NO_ARG:
        task_type = TaskType.Unknown
    else:
        task_type = arg
    def decorator(func):
        func.__task_type__ = task_type
        return func
    return decorator

def log_exceptions(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            # Behavior for logging exception into database
            ...
    return wrapper


Why not just initialize __task_type__ outside of executor?

The ultimate goal is to have an initial function dynamically find each decorated function, map them to their function type, and run a requested "pipeline" of inputted function names. I would like to contain the task_type argument solely in the decorator so that future authors can just decorate/mark their functions and not have to add additional information anywhere outside of their new functions.

The decorator could append the function to a list of decorated functions.

The function would have to be ran in order for the code within the decorator to be triggered and add to that list. Optimally, I'd like it so that I could use inspect or some similar library to just view the kwargs of the custom_task decoration within the my_task function.

@BenBole you aren't understanding what everyone is telling you. You keep saying "the function would have to be ran in order for the code within the decorator to be triggered*, what you mean is in order for the code in the wrapper that the decorator creates to be triggered. But you don't have to do it that way.

Just literally move func.__task_type__ = task_type to the top of def wrapper, don't put it inside def executor

so, moving the logging into it's own decorator is probably something that should be done anyway, but it isn't strictly necessary

You keep insisting that the function has to be ran, but that is only because of the way you are defining your decorator. Your decorator isn't really a decorator, you just want to use the decorator syntax to add an attribute to a function. So just do that, there is no need for creating and returning a wrapper function (which you call "executor")
def custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Unknown):
    def decorator(func):
        func.__task_type__ = task_type
        return func
    return decorator

Then you can do:
@custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Ingress)
def my_task(<arg1>, <arg2>, ...):
    ...

print(my_task.__task_type__)

Note, the way the above is defined, you need to use:
@custom_task()
def foo():
    ...

If you want to be able be able to use
@custom_task
def foo():
    ...

Then it gets a bit messy:
_NO_ARG = object()

def custom_task(arg=_NO_ARG):
    if callable(arg):
        func = arg
        func.__task_type__ = TaskType.Unknown
        return func
    if arg is _NO_ARG:
        task_type = TaskType.Unknown
    else:
        task_type = arg
    def decorator(func):
        func.__task_type__ = task_type
        return func
    return decorator

Here is an example of this working:
In [1]: import enum

In [2]: class TaskType(enum.Enum):
   ...:     Unknown = enum.auto()
   ...:     Ingress = enum.auto()
   ...:     Egress = enum.auto()
   ...:

In [3]: def custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Unknown):
   ...:     def decorator(func):
   ...:         func.__task_type__ = task_type
   ...:         return func
   ...:     return decorator
   ...:

In [4]: @custom_task(task_type=TaskType.Ingress)
   ...: def my_task(a, b):
   ...:     return a  + b
   ...:

In [5]: my_task.__task_type__
Out[5]: <TaskType.Ingress: 2>

In [6]: my_task(1,2)
Out[6]: 3


I also want to be able to run the function in the future, not just assign an attribute to a function. Doing something like this would not allow you to run the function.

@BenBole of course it will. You can just try it.

def wrapper_args(arg):
def decorator(func):
func.task_type = TaskType.Example
return func
return decorator
@wrapper_args('example')
def foo(s):
print('hello')
foo()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

@BenBole again, just try the code. The decorator just returns the function, you can call it. The code you have in this comment is not the code I provided

@BenBole I've added an example output from an IPython session showing you this working. I suspect your indentation is wrong

@juanpa.arrivilliaga Check edits.

@BenBole the same principle applies, the point is you have access the func when custom_task is called
